# conditional expectation of the number of points on a die given that it is odd and indepence of events

Tags: probability

A die is rolled.

1)What is the conditional expectation of the number of points given that it is odd?

2)The events "5 or 6 points" and "odd number of points" are not independent. Is it true? ( The answer is no. But I don't understand why)

Comment: What have you tried?  For the first, given the condition the only possibilities are $\{1,3,5\}$ with equal probability so...   For the second, calling the first event $A$ and the second $B$, what is $P(A)$?  What is $P(B)$?  What is $P(A\cap B)$?  What is $P(A\,|\,B)$?

Comment: P(B)=0.5, P(A)=1/3  and P of their intersection is 2/3

Comment: But how can I check the independence?

Comment: I understood the second. But for the first, how can I calculate it?

Comment: How do you see that $P(A\cap B)=\frac 23$?  What is $A\cap B$?

Comment: For the first, if you have a variable with possible values $\{a_i\}$ which occur with probabilities $\{p_i\}$ then the expectation is $\sum a_ip_i$.

Comment: Is P of their intersection 1/6?

Comment: Yes it is.  Now, recall that independence means that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Does that equality hold here?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let's define two random variables: $X$-number of points on a rolled side of a dice; $Y$ - rolled number of point is odd.
1). By definition:
$$E(X|Y) = \sum_{x \in \{1,3,5\}}{P(X=x|Y)x}$$
Let's calculate $P(X=x|Y=y)$:
$$P(X=x|Y=y)={{P(X \cap Y)} \over {P(Y)}} = {{1 \over 6} \over {1 \over 2}} = {1 \over 3}$$

Then 
$$E(X|Y) = \sum_{x \in \{1,3,5\}}{P(X=x|Y)x} = {1 \over 3}1 + {1 \over 3}3 + {1 \over 3}5 = 3$$

2). As of this one, let's introduce two events: $A$ - dice rolled "5" or "6" points; $B$ - dice rolled odd number of points. Then using one of the definitions of independence:
$$P(A|B) = P(A) $$

Intuitively, given that an odd number was rolled (B holds) means that the possible number of points is in $\{1,3,5\}$. Event A holds when either 5 or 6 was rolled. Given B, 6 obviously was not rolled (as the number rolled is odd), so the A can hold only if B rolled 5. The probability of B rolled 5 is exactly $1 \over 3$. This yields:
$$ P(A|B) = {1 \over 3}$$
Then what is the probabily of A holding on it's own. There are 6 possible values and all of them are equally likely. Thus $P(A) = {1 \over 3} = P(A|B)$. That means that event B causes no effect on event A and they are independent.

So the answer to the question from the second task is "no".

Comment: {{P(X \cap Y)} = 1/6

Comment: @Mary. Yes, indeed. I messed up with events as they are not the same as in the first task. I'll correct it ASAP.

Comment: If you find this answer correct please mark it as "accepted". Feel free to ask any questions.